# Getting HTTP 404 Not Found with multiple requests while using form based authentication

Tags: jsp, tomcat, authentication, websphere, j-security-check

I am having an issue with Tomcat and Websphere when users try to login in our application.

If a user presses multiple times the return key after entering his/her login details, the form is submitted multiple times.

Tomcat and Websphere don't ignore the multiple requests and end up complaining about the */j_security_check* url not being available.

After the error happens the solution is to restart the browser/tab, in order to get a new session.

Does anyone know of a possible solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Paulo

Comment: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the article seems to be related to general POST issues, and not to the login form, which I usually don't have any control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to disable the button on submit.

```
<form onsubmit="this.button.disabled=true">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about the problem. What do you mean? Don't the button get disabled?

Comment: I mean that disabling the button does not prevent the multiple requests from happening.

Comment: Actually your solution does work. I did see that there was an extra Javascript code that was also triggering submit requests.